# Local PC cannot connect to new Azure VM just created. Error-....server name cannot be resolved

Tags: powershell, azure, remote-access

Standard disclaimer, very new with powershell and Azure remote machines. Here is my powershell script. It is failing on this command:

$setupSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $pip -Port 5986 -Credential $serviceCreds -UseSSL

here is my script.

```
# Variables for common values
$resourceGroup = "rgTest"
$location = "East US"
$vmName = "vmTest"
$SubscriptionName = "subscription test"
$StorageAccountName = "sanTest"
$NetworkSecurityGroupName  = "nsgTest"
$myNic = 'nicTest'
$MYvNET = 'vnetTest'
$myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleHTTP = 'nsgruleHTTPTest'
$myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP = 'nsgruleRDPTest'
$myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleWWW = 'nsgruleWWWTest'
$myNetworkSecurityGroupRulePS = 'nsgrulePSTest'
$myNetworkSecurityGroup = 'nsgTest'
$rcgTest = 'rcgTest'

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password1" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("test@user.org", $secpasswd)

Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -ev notPresent -ea 0
if ($notPresent)
{
    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location $location
}

$subnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
   -Name mySubnet `
   -AddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24

New-AzureRmStorageAccount `
  -Location $Location `
  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
  –StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName `
  -SkuName Standard_GRS `
  -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName

$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
  -Location $location `
  -Name $MYvNET `
  -AddressPrefix 192.168.0.0/16 `
  -Subnet $subnetConfig

$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress ` 
   -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
   -Location $location `
   -Name "mypublicdns$(Get-Random)" `
   -AllocationMethod Static `
   -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4

$nsgRuleHTTP = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
  -Name $myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleHTTP  `
  -Protocol Tcp `
  -Direction Inbound `
  -Priority 1000 `
  -SourceAddressPrefix * `
  -SourcePortRange * `
  -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
  -DestinationPortRange 80 `
  -Access Allow

$nsgRuleRDP = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
   -Name $myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP  `
   -Protocol Tcp `
   -Direction Inbound `
   -Priority 1100 `
   -SourceAddressPrefix * `
   -SourcePortRange * `
   -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
   -DestinationPortRange 3389 `
   -Access Allow

$nsgRulePS = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
  -Name $myNetworkSecurityGroupRulePS  `
  -Protocol Tcp `
  -Direction Inbound `
  -Priority 1200 -SourceAddressPrefix * `
  -SourcePortRange * `
  -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
  -DestinationPortRange 5986 `
  -Access Allow

$nsg = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
  -Location $location `
  -Name $myNetworkSecurityGroup `
  -SecurityRules $nsgRuleHTTP,$nsgRuleRDP

$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface `
  -Name $myNic `
  -ResourceGroupName 

$resourceGroup 
   -Location $location `
   -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id `
   -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id `
   -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id

$VMLocalAdminUser = "LocalAdminUser"
$VMLocalAdminSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password1!" `
   -AsPlainText 
   -Force 

$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($VMLocalAdminUser, $VMLocalAdminSecurePassword); 

$vmConfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize Standard_DS1_v2 | ` 
   Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $Credential | `
   Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer -Offer WindowsServer -Skus 2016-Datacenter -Version latest | `
   Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id 

New-AzureRmVM `
     -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
     -Location $location `
     -VM $vmConfig

Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup | Select IpAddress

$PublicSettings = '{"commandToExecute":"powershell Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server"}'

Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts `
    -Value * #$pip.ToString() 

Enable-PSRemoting –Force

$serviceCreds = New-Object `
    -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
    -ArgumentList $VMLocalAdminUser, $VMLocalAdminSecurePassword

$setupSession = New-PSSession `
    -ComputerName $pip `
    -Port 5986 `
    -Credential $serviceCreds `
    -UseSSL

Remove-PSSession $setupSession
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, at no point do you associate your NSG's with your subnet. You need to run something like this

```
$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName TestRG -Name TestVNet
Set-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $vnet -Name FrontEnd `
-AddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24 -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg
```

Also if you might want to take a look at ARM templates, they make this much simpler.

Comment: Trying your change now....and I agree, but with that also being new, was told if learning it would take too long, then stick with powershell, so far I am...but will look at ARM when time permits.

Answer (score 0):

I test in my lab,in your script, there are some mistakes in your script. You don't add `$nsgRulePS` rules to your NSG. You need modify your script like below:

```
$nsg = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
  -Location $location `
  -Name $myNetworkSecurityGroup `
  -SecurityRules $nsgRuleHTTP,$nsgRuleRDP,$nsgRulePS
```

I modify your script like below, it works for me.

```
# Variables for common values
$resourceGroup = "rgTest"
$location = "East US"
$vmName = "vmTest"
$SubscriptionName = "subscription test"
##storage account name is wrong  New-AzureRmStorageAccount : sanTest is not a valid storage account name. Storage account name must be between 3 and 24 characters in length and use numbers and lower-case letters only.
#$StorageAccountName = "sanTest"
$StorageAccountName = "shuitest12"
$NetworkSecurityGroupName  = "nsgTest"
$myNic = 'nicTest'
$MYvNET = 'vnetTest'
$myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleHTTP = 'nsgruleHTTPTest'
$myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP = 'nsgruleRDPTest'
$myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleWWW = 'nsgruleWWWTest'
$myNetworkSecurityGroupRulePS = 'nsgrulePSTest'
$myNetworkSecurityGroup = 'nsgTest'
$rcgTest = 'rcgTest'

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password1" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("test@user.org", $secpasswd)

Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -ev notPresent -ea 0
if ($notPresent)
{
    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location $location
}

$subnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
   -Name mySubnet `
   -AddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24

New-AzureRmStorageAccount `
  -Location $Location `
  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
  –StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName `
  -SkuName Standard_GRS 

$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
  -Location $location `
  -Name $MYvNET `
  -AddressPrefix 192.168.0.0/16 `
  -Subnet $subnetConfig

$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
   -Location $location `
   -Name "mypublicdns$(Get-Random)" `
   -AllocationMethod Static `
   -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4

$nsgRuleHTTP = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
  -Name $myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleHTTP  `
  -Protocol Tcp `
  -Direction Inbound `
  -Priority 1000 `
  -SourceAddressPrefix * `
  -SourcePortRange * `
  -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
  -DestinationPortRange 80 `
  -Access Allow

$nsgRuleRDP = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
   -Name $myNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP  `
   -Protocol Tcp `
   -Direction Inbound `
   -Priority 1100 `
   -SourceAddressPrefix * `
   -SourcePortRange * `
   -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
   -DestinationPortRange 3389 `
   -Access Allow

$nsgRulePS = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
  -Name $myNetworkSecurityGroupRulePS  `
  -Protocol Tcp `
  -Direction Inbound `
  -Priority 1200 -SourceAddressPrefix * `
  -SourcePortRange * `
  -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
  -DestinationPortRange 5986 `
  -Access Allow

$nsg = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
  -Location $location `
  -Name $myNetworkSecurityGroup `
  -SecurityRules $nsgRuleHTTP,$nsgRuleRDP,$nsgRulePS

$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface `
  -Name $myNic `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
   -Location $location `
   -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id `
   -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id `
   -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id

##use name could not admin
$VMLocalAdminUser = "<your user name>"
$VMLocalAdminSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<your password>" `
   -AsPlainText `
   -Force 

$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($VMLocalAdminUser, $VMLocalAdminSecurePassword); 

$vmConfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize Standard_DS1_v2 | Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $Credential | `
   Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer -Offer WindowsServer -Skus 2016-Datacenter -Version latest | `
   Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id 

New-AzureRmVM `
     -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
     -Location $location `
     -VM $vmConfig

Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup | Select IpAddress
```

However, when the VM is created successful, you could not `winrm` the server directly. You need do the following steps:

1.Open port 5986 on your Windows VM, you need RDP to your VM and set it. Azure PowerShell could not do it.

2.Configure winrm listens on 5986, it is listening on 5985 by default. You also need add certificate on your VM. Please refer to this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/02/11/configuring-winrm-over-https-to-enable-powershell-remoting/).

Update:

If you want to use WinRM-HTTP not HTTPs, you don't need configure certificate on the VM, you only need open port 5985 on Windows Firewall.

Notes: You should open port 5985 on Azure NSG.

You could do it with [Custom Script Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript), it is executed when the VM is creating. Just your script as a ps file.

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WinRM-HTTP- Allow Port 5985" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 5985 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow
```

You could upload the script to Azure storage account or github.

More information about it please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript#powershell-deployment).

Comment: @Greg P Does it work?

Comment: Sorry..was never notified that there was new comments...looking at this now...thank you sir. Add certificate is something I was finding on my own, but I am glad you are pointing me in a certain direction. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: In reference to your point 1, is there no way to automate this? I have been tasked to try to build the server to build itself, set up the software testing pieces, and run it, and shut down the server and remove it every weekend. Basically build, run, destroy, automatically.....so we always have the most recent build of the ISO's etc.... Is number 1 not possible? without RDP'ing into it?

Comment: If you use your own image and run winrm on https, I think it is possible. Azure default images do not support this.

Comment: You could set winrm listening on https and configure ceritificate on it, open port 5986 on Windows firewall. Then you could caputer as your own image.

Comment: Sorry, I am not at office, if you have question, you could leave it at comment. I will update my answer tommower.

Comment: It seems that we needed to update the firewall, which we are able to do via powershell. New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WinRM-HTTP- Allow Port 5985" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 5985 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow

Comment: unfortunately we need the pssession to be enabled to run this remotely. So it is a cart before the horse scenario. What we are trying to use PSSession needs to be turned on to update the rule to allow us to use pssession.

Comment: @GregP, if you could use WinRM-HTTP not HTTPs, you don't need configure certificate. You could need open port 5985 on Windows Firewall. It is easy for you to do that without RDP to the VM. You could use CustomScript Extension. I will update my answer.

Comment: @GregP I test in my lab, you only need open ports on Windows firewall, then you could winrm your VM. `New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://IP:5985' -Credential $creds -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)` It works me perfect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59274/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-greg-p).